# No module named numpy error in python 2.7.8

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I'm trying to get Numpy working in Python 2.7.8, on a Ubuntu 12.0.4 operating system. I installed Python 2.7.8 as my default python, then installed the SciPy stack according to the site instructions. I double-checked that numpy installed in the /usr/lib/Python2.7 directory. When I run python the version is 2.7.8, but of course it can't find Numpy. Is there any way to fix this? Or should I just throw this computer out the window?

Edit: Apparently I have both 2.7.8 and 2.7.3 installed, both to Python2.7 directory. I have no idea how to get rid of either one...

Comment: *"according to the site instructions"* - [which instructions exactly](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/install.html)? Did you install it using `apt-get`? Using `pip`? Did you download the source and compile it yourself?